# bash script to search the words from a file into the whole server

Tags: bash, grep

Does anyone has any ideea about a script to set some words into a file and then use find grep or fgrep to search into the whole server

me i was thinking to something like this:

fgrep 'cat /root/my-wordfile' /home/*/*

but my ideea is not so great, i have try to find some things similar but at this moment i had no succes , yet

my script is based to search into the server files for some words , but the words i whant to add are more than 10 words , so a file with the words will be better instead of search every word by one command .

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved your patterns in the file `/root/my-wordfile`, then you can use the following to find "all" the files under `/home`

```
grep -rf /root/my-wordfile /home
```

-r would search it recursively and -f would say the patterns are in /root/my-wordfile(separated by newline)

Or if you want to search files with specific extension or names, you could use `find` as below:

```
For example if you want to search all *.c files
find /home -name *.c -exec grep -Hnf /root/my-wordfile {} \;
```

Here -H would list the file name, -n would display line number.

Comment: thanks , but on my my-wordfile , how should i enter the word , like word1,word2,word3, or "word1" "word2" etc... ?

Comment: It should be newline separated. That was already written in the answer :-)